# What is this setting?

Tags: windows, audio

How is the headset microphone slider here different from the "listen to this device" setting found under recording devices?

See image here:
[image]

This post says they are different:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328085/how-to-enable-sidetone-microphone-pass-thru-programmatically/43523842#43523842?newreg=434295c600444c1d9ba5253bbcc0f165

I don't know what that difference is other than that you can attenuate the signal coming from the mic.

Answer (score 0):

If you see input line related sliders in the "Levels" tab of a playback device/endpoint, they controls *analog monitoring*. Analog monitoring means that audio signals are internally (inside the audio device) passed from the appropriate inputs to the output. No digital [sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)), conversion or other processing is performed, except of simple volume control. Therefore, no latency is added, output signals are no delays relative to input ones. Windows Audio Subsystem is not involved in signal transmission process. Analog monitoring is available only within the same audio device.

The "Listen to" feature performs *digital monitoring*. Windows Audio Subsystem creates an internal recording [stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media) and records digital audio samples from the endpoint like any other audio application. Recorded samples are immediately played back to the selected audio endpoint, which may belong to a different device. Audio format conversion may occur in such case. And, due to [data buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer), there always is some [latency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_(audio)) (lag) between output and input signals.

Answer (score 0):

- *Listen to this device* checked → you hear what your mic hears
- *Listen to this device* unchecked → you don't hear yourself, but the mic still works

The slider controls volume of the microphone and lets you mute it for everyone.